# convert time of certain timezone to UTC using momemtjs

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have a time in a specific timezone , I want to covert it to UTC . how can I achieve that using moment timezone ?

http://momentjs.com/timezone/

in the documentation this is how to convert :
`jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');`

I am just not sure what timezone name to pass to convert it to UTC, or is there another function to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily construct a moment in a specific time zone by using the `moment.tz(...)` syntax.  This is slightly different from doing conversions with the `.tz(...)` function of an *existing* moment object, which is what you showed in your question.

```
var m = moment.tz('2016-03-25 08:00:00', 'America/Los_Angeles')
```

Once you have a `moment` object, you can convert it to UTC by calling the `.utc()` function.  You can then format it however you like.

```
moment.tz('2016-03-25 12:34:56', 'America/Los_Angeles').utc().format()
// output: "2016-03-25T19:34:56+00:00"
```