# Why is the value output by MomentJS not reflecting UTC time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get a particular day/time in UTC format. Example code

```
  const today = moment().tz('America/New_York')
  const tomorrow = today.add(1, 'days')
  const formatTime = today.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  const time = '7:00 pm'
  const deliveryTime = moment(`${formatTime} ${time}`)
  console.log(deliveryTime.utc().format())
```

Shouldn't I be getting this as output `2019-10-01T19:00:00Z` as I am getting it on https://repl.it/@azs06/SilkyBronzeInversion
Suppose to `2019-10-02T13:00:00Z` this on https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/hkrvze1x/2/

Is this is because of Node.js implementation of date?

What would be proper way to convert date time to UTC using moment.js?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*convert time of certain timezone to UTC using momemtjs*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214634/convert-time-of-certain-timezone-to-utc-using-momemtjs).

Comment: `deliveryTime` is not created in a specific time zone.